# Last label on xaxis disappears when resize

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to force highcharts to show last label on x-axis when "step" is enabled. Code below works but it hides last label when I change device width (let's say open chrome console). Problem arises on mobile devices when I scroll down after the chart, last label disappears.

```
   chart:
   {
        renderTo: "container",
        type: "line",
        events:{
             load:function(){
                 var ticks = $.map(this.axes[0].ticks, function(t){return t;});
                   ticks[ticks.length-2].render(0);
            }
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the last label `2020` is appearing because of your logic in `load` event. Ideally that label shouldn't be appearing because your step value is 3. Anyways, you need to add the same logic of `load` in `redraw` event to get the last label on resize.

```
const df = [
  { Period: 2009, value: 1056043 },
  { Period: 2010, value: 1278495 },
  { Period: 2011, value: 1482508 },
  { Period: 2012, value: 1545703 },
  { Period: 2013, value: 1579593 },
  { Period: 2014, value: 1620531.9 },
  { Period: 2015, value: 1502572.2 },
  { Period: 2016, value: 1451010.7 },
  { Period: 2017, value: 1546273 },
  { Period: 2018, value: 1663982.3 },
  { Period: 2019, value: 1643160.9 },
  { Period: 2020, value: 1431638.4 }
];

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart: {
    renderTo: "container",
    height: 300,
    type: "areaspline",
    events: {
      load: function () {
        var ticks = $.map(this.axes[0].ticks, function (t) {
          return t;
        });
        ticks[ticks.length - 2].render(0);
      },
      redraw: function () {
        var ticks = $.map(this.axes[0].ticks, function (t) {
          return t;
        });
        ticks[ticks.length - 2].render(0);
      }
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: "Emissions of CO2 - from Fossil Fuels - Total (CDIAC)"
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: df.map((o) => o.Period),
    labels: {
      step: 3,
      style: {
        fontFamily: "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;",
        fontSize: "0.8rem",
        fontWeight: "600",
        background: "#000000",
        whiteSpace: "nowrap",
        textOverflow: "none"
      }
    },
    showLastLabel: true,
    endOnTick: true,
    overflow: "allow"
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0
  },
  series: [
    {
      data: df.map((o) => o.value),
      name: "Germany"
    }
  ]
});
```